# In Symfony 2, can you submit changes to hidden and disabled for fields?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

In Symfony 2, if a field is hidden or disabled and someone tampers the HTML to edit the value of those fields, will Symfony invalidate the form?

Comment: Why you don't test that, instead?

Comment: Because I had inconclusive results and couldn't find this behaviour specified in the documentation. But you are right and I continue testing.

Comment: Hidden, no. Disabled, the nature of HTML won't even pass the value to the server, UNLESS the `disabled` property is removed by the user as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a field is hidden then yes, the value will persist. If you are worried about people changing those values then you should either validate the contents on submit or not use them at all and handle those values in the backend.

If the field is disabled in the actual form type rather (than client side) then it will be ignored when handling the request as you can see in [the code](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/Form.php#L516-L521).

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function submit($submittedData, $clearMissing = true)
{
    ...

    // Obviously, a disabled form should not change its data upon submission.
    if ($this->isDisabled()) {
        $this->submitted = true;
        return $this;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. Perfect. I realize that anything coming from the client side can't be trusted but I also knew that symfony simply knows that to expect as long as we use a form type.